# Can "drunk" be used as a noun?

Tags: american-english

I was reading [Post Office](https://books.google.com/books?id=XjQ5zlnQ8ZcC&pg=PA14&dq=%22The%20soup%20was%20a%20bullneck%20named%20Jonstone.%22) and the very first sentence looked a little off to me

"It was Christmas season and I learned from the **drunk up the hill**,
who did **the trick every Christmas**, that they would hire damned
near anybody, and so I went and the next thing I knew I had this
leather sack on my back and was hiking around at my leisure."

What I did understand from the sentence is  that he got to know about the job from a drunkard. Am I correct?

If anyone has read read the novel or the author before. I wanted to ask this regarding the novel:
The tone in general of the novel is very informal and conversational. I wanted to know how popular is this way of speaking. Is it specific to certain states in US or it is more of a nationwide phenomenon?
The author seems to be brought up near Ohio and California.

Comment: See: [Drunk (noun)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/drunk)

Comment: @Cascabel Sorry, it was foolish of me to not look up the word first.

Comment: 'drunkard' is a bit old-fashioned. 'drunk' is the more common term recently. [Of course, that is going out of favor too since it is somewhat derogatory.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+drunkard%2Cthe+drunk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). I'm not sure what would be used nowadays, in speech or writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll speak from my experience (middle-aged male, living primarily in the northeastern U.S., Chicago, and briefly in Los Angeles, as well as communicating with people around the country): "drunk" is by far the more common noun. To my ear, "drunkard" has an old and formal feeling to it.

Comment: I am giving you a provisional upvote...consider linking the citation to a reputable general reference.